# Find out which div is containing the "main content" with crawler

Tags: html, parsing, web-crawler

We have a crawler that is crawling hundreds of thousands of pages per week. Currently to get the data from the crawled HTML we manually take a look at the HTML and see that "OK, Data A is within `<div class=".info-list">` and Data B is inside `<h1>`", and then we use a parser to parse the data from those div's.

I guess this is the most common way to parse crawled HTML for most people, but it means that we have to know the HTML structure of all the pages and domains that we crawl. So it is not very scalable.

If we could just figure out what div the "main content" is, so that we can ignore other things such as "Relevant products" or "Relevant articles", or "Main menu" and so on, we could easily parse the data in the same way as we do now but without having to specify the exact div names and position of each data.

So... How do we figure out which is the "main div" of a page?

I'm pretty sure that Google does this. They definitely know position of elements on a page, and if something is positioned in the "main content" or in the footer for example. How can they know this?

The methods that I can see to do this in a large scale is:

- Render the page and look for the largest div's and start from there. But to render millions or hundreds of thousands of pages is not really cheap and efficient.
- Try to figure it out from the content of every div. For example, the div with most links inside of it is probably the menu. The div with most text inside of it is probably the main content. But this gets really tricky if the content is like:

  ```
  <body>
      <div class="maincontent">
          <div class="post-header">
              <h1>Header of post</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="short-description">
              Hello World!
          </div>
          <div class="long-description">
              Hello New World!
          </div>
      </div>
  </body>
  ```

  Obviously the div we want to identify as the "main content" is `<div class="maincontent">`. But if we look for the div that have "most text". It would be `.long-description`.

This is starting to become quite a long question. But my point is, it's really hard to figure out which part of a website that is the "main content". And I'm asking any smart people out there to help me come up with a decent way to find out what div or divs that is probably containing the most important content of the page.

EDIT: I guess one way of rendering it is not to render every single page. But to render the domain. For example. If the domain structure is http://example.com/post/1-post-name/ I can save a render of that, and next time I find a page that is http://example.com/post/2-post-name/ I know that it probably have the same HTML template as the first one, and the "largest div" is probably the same.

So what techinique to do this server side? I mean to render it and to save the sizes and position of all the elements. I guess this seems to be a pretty decent way of doing it on large scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really find a great way to decide which div is the "main content" yet, however I found [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) which lets you render the page you are crawling on server side, and be able to use Javascript and jQuery to get sizes and positions of elements on the page you are crawling.

So by using PhantomJS you can definitely get which div is the "largest", which div is on top or bottom or center, which is a long way already on solving this issue of finding out which div on a page that is the "main content".

Comment: Hi I'm working in similar script . I just figure out out how to detect (bigger Div) . I use simple_html_dom to find all div in the page . 
inside the loop I'll add each div value to associative array 
`foreach($e=$html->find('div') as $div){
$diva["div-$i"]=$div->plaintext;`

After loop finished I'll compare and delete bottom div text from upper div . 
`$diva["div-$0"]=str_replace($diva["div-4"],'',$diva["div-$0"]);` and so on .
    
    so the result will be unique contents for each Div alone without Div inside it .  that's solves issue #1 from what you was looking for .

Answer (score 0):

I would try multiple approaches. For example start with the obvious - is there an `id="content"` or `class="main_content"` ? Use it! Look for ids and classes that are common for big content blocks and if they exist then use them. If not then move on to less certain tests.

Next try narrowing things down. is there a `<header>` or `<nav>` tag? ignore that and everything above it. Ignore a `<footer>` or a class="sidebar"

Make some rules, let them run, and then manually expect what comes back and look for patterns when you're pulling too much or things are being left out. Adjust your rules and write new ones based on that.

At that point you might even let the ones get past all your tests go to a short list where you check them by hand and create domain specific rules where you can point out the exact div you want to use. You can still be very efficient with some human intervention, and visually looking over 8 sites out of 50 is still a pretty good deal.

Comment: See edit to my post regarding rendering and cache the renders to other pages with same html templates. What do you think?

We already do domain-specific rules as you suggest. And that is what we want to get away from. You are right that you can get "good results" with that, and we already got good results. But we are looking to improve beyond that to scale much faster.

Comment: I don't like the rendering idea, my gut reaction is that it would be more trouble than it's worth. If I were automating this process my answer is exactly how I would go about it. You understand that the computer should parse and check for the things I said, right? A human  looking at it is only a fallback for when none of your automated tests work for a page.

Comment: Ofcourse, but if you want to crawl 1000+ domains that all have different HTML structures you don't want to do "hardcoded rules" to parse things because if they just do a single change it all breaks. 

To find an automated process that can handle any domain without any human input or assistance is what we are looking for. Google does this on billion of pages, we are looking to do this on a couple of hundred thousand of pages.

Looking for an automated way to find the right content on ANY page or domain. WITHOUT human input.

Comment: I'm afraid you're misunderstanding my approach. I'm working on two automation projects right now I understand you don't want to take up the humans time. You're not going to get there with just one rule or regular expression that works in all cases. Look at how adblock works and consider why there is a slider when blocking a new ad.